# Confusion on SQLite Tables & Virtual Tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, virtual, fts4

I am currently developing a notebook application for the Android environment, however I am stuck on how to approach a SQL search interface. From conducting research, I have found the most effective approach would be to use the "Full Text Search" module (FTS4).

What I am stuck on is the way which I have to handle this. Do I have to:

1. Create both a Note Table and a Virtual Table and use a simple Trigger logic to insert into both tables.

or

2. Do I create a Virtual Table ONLY and maintain the list of Notes within there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create a virtual table and maintain list of nodes within there. That is my understanding after reading [FTS doc](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

Comment: Yh I was actually thinking along the same lines to be honest as the doc wasn't clear on maintaining both tables or just one of them, thank for the answer